# Multiple if statements comparing text and integers

Tags: c++, objective-c, if-statement

I am trying to make multiple if statements with multiple conditions. If I run the code it works fine but it never changes the output. I always get the second statement >= 29. Here's my code.

```
 if (label.text <= @"30") 
    {label.text = @"Text";}   
else if (label.text >= @"29") 
    {label.text = @"Text";} 
else if (label.text >= @"19")
    {label.text = @"Text";}
else if (label.text >= @"10") 
    {label.text = @"Text";}
else if (label.text  = @"00") 
    {label.text = @"Text";}
```

ok I have changed my code but i still doesn't work any suggestions

```
      label.text = temporaryValue;
     if ([label.text floatValue] <= 30) 
         {label.text = @"text1";}   
else if ([label.text floatValue] >= 29) 
         {label.text = @"text2";}   
else if ([label.text floatValue] >= 19)
         {label.text = @"text3";}
else if ([label.text floatValue] >= 10) 
         {label.text = @"text4";}
else if ([label.text floatValue] == 0) 
         {label.text = @"text5";}
```

Comment: How do u know it always give the second one? You set the text to the same value each time

Answer (score 5):

You  can't compare the  numerical values of a string like this; this operation performs pointer comparison, i. e. it compares the (rather random) addresses of the string instances you pass in. Use something like this:

```
if ([label.text floatValue] >= 30.0) {
}
```

etc.

Comment: ok that kind of worked except the button on witch i activate the if statment i have to hit it multiple times untill it gets the correct output. Would you know what to do against that?

Comment: @MattMühlemann that's not the problem of my answer -- that's a problem of your code. You're modifying the value of label.text whilst examining it in the if statement -- you'd better set a temporary variable then use it to set label.text **outside** the if statement.

Comment: what do you mean with set label.text outside of the if statement? my label .text has a value and according to that value i want to change the label.text to a sentence

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested to set a temporary variable in the if statement according to your wish, then use `label.text = temporaryValue` outside the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Using >= or <= with `NSString*` would compare the addresses, not the content of those strings.  If you want to compare like this, you should parse your string into an `int` and compare it using common integer comparison:

```
int val = [label.text intValue];
if (val > 30) {
   ...
}
else ... // more of your ifs
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your syntax (as suggested in other answers here) you will still have a problem, as once you are dealing with numeric comparisons your logic flow seems flawed. Consider this

```
if ([label.text floatValue]  <= 30.0) 
    {label.text = @"Text";}   
else if ([label.text floatValue]  >= 29.0) 
    {label.text = @"Text";}
```

if your test value IS greater than 30, you move to the next else if

```
else if ([label.text floatValue]  >= 29.0)
```

clearly this IS bigger than 29 since it failed to be less than or equal to 30. Therefore all your other conditonals are never reached as assuming your first conditional is false, the second MUST be true.

Comment: He will still have a logic flow problem after your corrections if dealing with numeric values.

Comment: Yes (that's why you didn't get a downvote), but this is not an answer to his question.

Comment: Fair enough - but when he makes YOUR correction my answer will help him solve the next one. I did specify that `Assuming you fix your syntax`

Comment: OK you win - but the primary problem is still the same.

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree you have the answer - I am not bothered with downvotes - just want the guy to get his code working as intended. I just couldnt explain all that just with a comment.

Comment: Ive edited my answer to make it clear that he needs to use yours first

Comment: that's nice of you (and +1 in the meantime, btw)